# How to unrar in Objective-C (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone

I need to unrar some files in Objective-C (iPhone). I tried to compile the unrar sources in xcode, but failed.

Appreciate it if some experts could teach me how to unrar in Objective-C (iPhone).

Any suggestions is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What does "failed" mean? If you report your problems in detail, maybe someone can help you past the difficulties.

Comment: I created an empty iPhone project in xcode, and added the unrar sources. When I built it, a lot of errors prompted out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile/use unrar C++ source for iphone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705181/compile-use-unrar-c-source-for-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do a successful build of unrar sources, however I need help with an example project and further fixes.

Here's the github project:

https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS

Comment: This project is ready for mostly basic functions, like list files and extract files from archive as NSData.

Answer (score 0):

personally i use ZipArchive Library it can uncompress anything for me so far with Encryption method such as AES.

Have a look at their site http://www.artpol-software.com/ i can help you compiling the library.

if you're insist to use unrar library please let me know what you're facing exactly to provide with the appropriate help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I need to do unrar.